# WinCE SOAP/Webservice Client C/C++

Tags: visual-c++, soap, windows-ce, webservice-client

I want to write a SOAP/webservice client in C++ for a WinCE 7 device. During my research I noticed that I could use SOAP Toolkit, and also MSXML. Microsofts' code samples are not so self explanatory, does anyone have any useful resources?

My first choice would be for SOAP Toolkit. Is it a good a choice, are other choices available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at gSOAP ([www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soap.html)). I have just been trying it out for a project where I need a webservice *host* running on Windows CE 6.0, and it was very easy to get running. The library has support for both host and client so it should work for you as well. Even though I have just started working with it, I would say that it looks like a very mature library with a lot of features.

Comment: Thnx Allan, I will take a look today over the library. I did find out something too: Pocket SOAP - http://www.pocketsoap.com/ which looks handy too.

Comment: I really like this project, I would this link to the latest gSOAP version: http://genivia.com/Products/index.html It's a really simple to use tool.